# Mi dato no llega al input del dialog [Angular Material]

Tags: angular, material-design

Hola muy buenas estoy desarrollando un crud simple en .net y angular, tengo un dialog que utilizo para insertar y editar datos pero al momento de editar el dialog no muestra los datos a editar.

Mi codigo ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ApitrademarkService } from 'src/app/services/apitrademark.service';
import { Trademark } from 'src/app/models/trademark';

export class DialogtrademarkComponent implements OnInit {

  public tmId: number;
  public tmName: string;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogtrademarkComponent>,
    public apiTrademark: ApitrademarkService,

    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public trademark: Trademark
  ) {
      if(this.trademark != null){
        this.tmName = trademark.TmName;
      }
   }

editTrademark(){
    const trademark: Trademark = {
      TmId: this.tmId, TmName: this.tmName
    };
    this.apiTrademark.editTrademark(trademark).subscribe(response => {
      if(response.success){
        this.dialogRef.close();
        this.snackBar.open('Changes saved successfully!', '', {
          duration: 3000
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

mi codigo html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title> {{ trademark !=null ? 'Edit File' : 'New File' }} </h1>

<div mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-form-field>
    <label>Trademark Name </label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="tmName">
    {{trademark.TmName}}
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
    (click)="trademark != null ? editTrademark() : addTrademark()">Save</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="close()" >Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Nota: El h1 si cumple la condición cuando abro el dialog en editar o nuevo registro.